# Canvas matrix rotate and translate

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have this

```
        m = new Matrix();
        m.setTranslate(100, 150);
```

result

[image]

```
        m = new Matrix();
        m.setTranslate(100, 150);
        m.preRotate(180, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight());
```

[image]

```
        m = new Matrix();
        m.setTranslate(100, 150);
        m.preRotate(270, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight());
```

[image]

I'm using canvas.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, paint);
```

Bitmap is a single line, the circle is a background.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The problem was in the bitmap, it was 9x62px.
After placing bitmap on a transparent background with 124x124 everything become as needed.

Comment: What is the final output you want ?

Comment: Like an analog clock

Comment: You circle would be fixed and you have to change the line position ondraw() ..post your code

Comment: there is my code above, it should be done with canvas.
I can't use a simple line, my line is a bitmap